# activate mod_rewrite for PHP in beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I been swimming in the AWS documentation and become sunk...

I recently uploaded my php project using Elastic Beanstalk, but when O try to access any URL that is not the home, I get a 404 not found. I think is a `.htaccess` related problem or `mod_rewrite` problem. But I can't find in the documentation where to go to activate, access, or any clue where to investigate next...

My local `.htaccess` looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: -SOLVED- Remember to unhide `.htaccess` before upload to AWS :) ...

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution. It is acceptable and actually encouraged to provide a real answer to your own question if you figure out a solution later on so that it isn't listed as 'unanswered' anymore, thereby making room for other unanswered questions.

Comment: what do you mean by 'unhide' here @Xisco?